# Product.where(:tags => nil) returns empty results, yet it should have thousands of records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Weird one. I have a model Product.rb, I have 10k products. I have title, description, link, brand and tag columns. Product.where(:tags => nil) doesn't work, not via console or via method in the model.

Is this something ridiculously simple that I'm doing wrong?

(I haven't even got code I can include, its literally as simple as that one single command wont work :/)

Thanks,

Geoff

Comment: what doesn't work? it doesn't return any rows?  I assume there are rows where tag is nil (and not just empty value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a product has no tags, do you actually store null values in the `tags` column or do you store an empty string?  Try this:

```
Product.where(:tags => "")
```

If that doesn't work try running these SQL queries and tell us what the results are:

```
select * from products where tags is null;
select * from products where tags = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

`Product.where(:tags => nil)` is looking for a column named 'tags' do you have one or is 'tags' a relation?

You can see what sql is being produced like so:

```
Product.where(:tags => nil).to_sql #=> SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."tags" IS NULL
```

Comment: I do, it was the problem mentioned below!